# Why localhost absolute url works but publish

Tags: angular, angular8

In my `localhost:4200`, directly entering Absolute URL like below is working fine.

```
http://localhost:4200/blogs/1
http://localhost:4200/blogs/2
http://localhost:4200/blogs/3
```

However after publish to `IIS/Azure CDN`, I get below error.

> 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for
>   might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable.

Navigating through a routerLink `<span routerLink="/blogs/1">Blog1</span>` works as expected.

My Router looks below

```
{ path: 'blogs', component: BlogsComponent },
{ path: 'blogs/:id', component: BlogComponent }
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **web.config** file in the folder where you have published.

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Sorry, I finally need to publish this to Azure CDN where I do not have facility to re-write rules.

Comment: Specify where people need to write the code you posted in your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your IIS has to be configured to redirect all urls starting with your basehref to your index.html page.

Angular router starts working after the document(`index.html`, and subsequently `main.js`) has been loaded.
Your IIS is probably trying to handle complete address on its own. 
You need to tell it to redirect all the urls with

```
https://your-site/**
```

to your index.html.